# Android Volley NullPointerException without any explanation

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I have 3 functions that are uploading images and setting the name of an image on a server. The thing is, I can't get all functions to work at a time. Only one function works and the other throws a NullPointerException that aren't pointing to anything specific but just the first line in the function.

```
private void uploadMainImage()
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest ppRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL_IMAGE_MAIN , new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            System.out.println("Response[Job Image Main]: " + response.toString());
            uploadThumbImage();
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            System.out.println("Job Image profile Error: " + error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.hide();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("ImageName",jobID + "-1.jpg");
            params.put("base64", pp_finalImage);
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(ppRequest);
}

private void uploadThumbImage()
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest ppRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL_IMAGE_THUMB , new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {
            System.out.println("Response[Job Image Thumb]: " + response.toString());
            //updateImageName();
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            System.out.println("Job Thumb Image profile Error: " + error.getMessage());
            progressDialog.hide();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("ImageName",jobID + "-1.jpg");
            params.put("base64", thumb_finalImage);
            return params;
        }
    };

    queue.add(ppRequest);
}

private void updateImageName()
{
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("USER_DETAILS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userID = prefs.getString("USER_ID", "NO_SESSION");

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("postpicture  ", jobID + "-1.jpg");
    params.put("userid", "1");
    params.put("postjobid ", jobID);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL + "updateJobPostImage" ,new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Response[Image Name Update Job]: " + response.toString());
            try
            {
                String status = response.getString("result");
                if(status.equals("Success"))
                {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                else
                {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG," Image Name Update Failed, Aborting.");
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            progressDialog.hide();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Image Name Update Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(request);
}
```

This is the log

```
04-30 00:41:29.074 14041-14041/com.antisaby.trackit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.antisaby.trackit, PID: 14041
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:43)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
                                                                      at fragments.homefragments.AddServiceFragment.uploadThumbImage(AddServiceFragment.java:397)
                                                                      at fragments.homefragments.AddServiceFragment.access$1100(AddServiceFragment.java:50)
                                                                      at fragments.homefragments.AddServiceFragment$8.onResponse(AddServiceFragment.java:368)
                                                                      at fragments.homefragments.AddServiceFragment$8.onResponse(AddServiceFragment.java:363)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
```

The uploadMainImage function executes first. If the response is good, it calls uploadThumbImage. If the result of uploadThumbImage is good, it calls updateImageName. If i don't comment out any function, the exception occurs in the uploadThumbImage function. If i comment out the first function, exception occurs in the last function. If I try to catch the exception, the message comes out to be null.

Comment: i think `getActivity()` is null, check `isAdded()` on first line of the method

Comment: I checked it with isAdded() function and it returns false in the function where it fails. What could be the reason? Why does all the functions before this function works but this one fails when the code is in single fragment?

Comment: okay I solved it. I was calling `getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);` in another function before all these and I forgot to remove it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> A key concept is that the RequestQueue must be instantiated with the Application context, not an Activity context. This ensures that the RequestQueue will last for the lifetime of your app, instead of being recreated every time the activity is recreated (for example, when the user rotates the device).

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html)